# Split and type cast columns values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do i add an extra column in a dataframe, so it could split and convert to integer types but np.nan for string types

```
Col1   
1|2|3
"string"
```

so

```
Col1      ExtraCol
1|2|3     [1,2,3]
"string"  nan
```

I tried long contorted way but failed

```
df['extracol'] = df["col1"].str.strip().str.split("|").str[0].apply(lambda x: x.astype(np.float) if x.isnumeric() else np.nan).astype("Int32")
```

Comment: I would suggest to write a specific function inside the lambda with some try-except with your specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
import re

df['ExtraCol'] = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in re.split(
    r'\|', x)] if x.replace('|', '').isnumeric() else np.nan)
```

Output:

```
     Col1   ExtraCol
0   1|2|3  [1, 2, 3]
1  string        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and [`Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) to find the rows whose value can be split into integer lists

```
df['ExtraCol'] = df.loc[df['Col1'].str.match(r'\|?\d+\|?'), 'Col1'].str.split('|')
```